# argparse action or type for comma-separated list

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to create a command line flag that can be used as

```
./prog.py --myarg=abcd,e,fg
```

and inside the parser have this be turned into `['abcd', 'e', 'fg']` (a tuple would be fine too).

I have done this successfully using `action` and `type`, but I feel like one is likely an abuse of the system or missing corner cases, while the other is right. However, I don't know which is which.

With `action`:

```
import argparse

class SplitArgs(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values.split(','))


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--myarg', action=SplitArgs)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.myarg)
```

Instead with `type`:

```
import argparse

def list_str(values):
    return values.split(',')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--myarg', type=list_str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.myarg)
```

Comment: Yet another option - split the `args.myarg` string after parsing.  They are all doing the same thing, just at different times.  Or you could specify `nargs='+'` (or 3), and input '--myarg abcd e fg'.

Comment: Be careful when expecting a comma separated list - it gets messed up if the user includes spaces.  '--myarg=abcd,e, fg'.  Unless they quote the string:  '--myarg "abcd, e, fg"'.  That's part of why there isn't anything builtin.

Comment: @hpaulj That is pretty easily handled with a comprehension that excludes empty values. `setattr(namespace, self.dest, [v for v in values.split(',') if v])`

Comment: Unless you need a comma separated list specifically, it may be better to use [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs), which seems to be the native way of taking a number of arguments that are all on the same form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your first solution to be the right one. The reason is that it allows you to better handle defaults:

```
names: List[str] = ['Jane', 'Dave', 'John']

parser = argparse.ArumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--names', default=names, action=SplitArgs)

args = parser.parse_args()
names = args.names
```

This doesn't work with list_str because the default would have to be a string.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution is to consider your argument as a string and split.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--myarg", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.myarg is not None:
    args.myarg = [s.strip() for s in args.myarg.split(",")]
print(args)
```

Result:

```
$ ./toto.py --myarg=abcd,e,fg
Namespace(myarg=['abcd', 'e', 'fg'])
$ ./toto.py --myarg="abcd, e, fg"
Namespace(myarg=['abcd', 'e', 'fg'])
```

Comment: This is a good solution, because the approaches suggested by Ryan both try to wrangle some functionality into the add_argument method of argparse, when in effect the required task here is the processing of the argument received. As noted by hpaulj, there is no clear default definition of how an argument list should look like and whether it is, for example, a list of strings, a list of ints, floats, or whatever. According to the documentation of argparse, the meaning of _action_ is something different, and "list" is not a valid _type_ in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my solution using `type` with lambda for the conversion:

```py
parser.add_argument(
  "--myarg",
  default="abc,d,ef",  # conversion only happens if default is a string
  type=lambda t: [s.strip() for s in t.split(',')],
)
```

This is more concise so I think it might be helpful. For more details around `type` check Python's doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#type) (links to py3.7, but it is the same for later Python versions).

Comment: I had spelled out `list_str` with my `type` version since I thought it made sense to give a name for something called `type` like that, but yes this works too of course

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I recently found myself solving this exact problem.  I used [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for a lightweight solution:

```py
import argparse

from functools import partial

csv_ = partial(str.split, sep=',')

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--stuff', type=csv_)
p.parse_args(['--stuff', 'a,b,c'])
# Namespace(stuff=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

If you're not familiar with `functools.partial`, it allows you to create a partially "frozen" function/method.  In the above example, I created a new function (`csv_`) that is essentially a copy of `str.split()` except that the `sep` argument has been "frozen" to the comma character.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom action is the closest way to how it is done internally for other argument types. IMHO there should be a `_StoreCommaSeperatedAction` added to argparse in the stdlib since it is a somewhat common and useful argument type,

It can be used with an added default as well.

Here is an example without using an action (no SplitArgs class):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._names: List[str] = ["Jane", "Dave", "John"]

    @property
    def names(self):
        return self._names

    @names.setter
    def names(self, value):
        self._names = [name.strip() for name in value.split(",")]


test_object = Test()
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-n",
    "--names",
    dest="names",
    default=",".join(test_object.names),  # Joining the default here is important.
    help="a comma separated list of names as an argument",
)
print(test_object.names)
parser.parse_args(namespace=test_object)
print(test_object.names)
```

Here is another example using SplitArgs class inside a class completely

```
    """MyClass
Demonstrates how to split and use a comma separated argument in a class with defaults
"""
import sys
from typing import List
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Action


class SplitArgs(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # Be sure to strip, maybe they have spaces where they don't belong and wrapped the arg value in quotes
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, [value.strip() for value in values.split(",")])


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.names: List[str] = ["Jane", "Dave", "John"]
        self.parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
        self.parser.add_argument(
            "-n",
            "--names",
            dest="names",
            default=",".join(self.names),  # Joining the default here is important.
            action=SplitArgs,
            help="a comma separated list of names as an argument",
        )
        self.parser.parse_args(namespace=self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.argv)
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.names)
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], "--names", "miigotu, sickchill,github"]
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.names)
```

And here is how to do it in a function based situation, with a default included

```
class SplitArgs(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # Be sure to strip, maybe they have spaces where they don't belong and wrapped the arg value in quotes
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, [value.strip() for value in values.split(",")])

names: List[str] = ["Jane", "Dave", "John"]
parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument(
    "-n",
    "--names",
    dest="names",
    default=",".join(names),  # Joining the default here is important.
    action=SplitArgs,
    help="a comma separated list of names as an argument",
)
parser.parse_args()
```